# How to claim claimable balances using a MEXC XLM wallet?

Tags: stellar-laboratory

I input my MEXC XLM wallet address into stellar expert and saw that I had claimable balances!  I did the whole thing on trying to convert a claimable asset to XLM.  I got to the part where I was asked to input my secret key?

[image]

I tried to input the secret key MEXC provided through their API.  When I submitted my transaction I got a

[image]

So I'm stuck and was wondering can I do this with MEXC?